# How do I find the sum using a loop function?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, sum

I was able to loop a file that gave me the miles driven, gallons used, and gasoline cost at a certain day successfully. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the sum of miles driven, gallons used, and gasoline cost by using loops

```
int main()
{                     
   ifstream inputFile;            
   int    x = 1;
   int    milesDriven = 0; 
   double gallonsUsed = 0, 
   gasolineCost = 0;
   int truckNumber,
   numberOfTrips, 
   sumMilesDriven = 0;
   double  sumGallonsUsed = 0, 
   sumGasolineCost = 0;
   int     avgMilesDriven;
   double  avgGallonsUsed,
   avgGasolineCost;

   /*          Display Truck Information
      Get Number of Trips 
      Get Truck Information
      Process Each Trip 
      Display Averages
   */ 

   inputFile.open("100.txt");

   //Display Truck Information
   cout << " " << setw(35) << "Red-Rig Trucking" << endl << endl;
   cout << " " << setw(40) << "Summary of Truck Operations" << endl << endl;
   inputFile >> truckNumber;
   cout << "Truck: " << truckNumber << endl << endl; 

   inputFile.close( );

   inputFile.open("truck.txt");

   //Get Number of Trips
   inputFile >> numberOfTrips;

   //Get Truck Information
   cout << "Day" << " " <<setw(16) << "Miles" << " " << setw(16) << "Gallons" 
   << " " << setw(16) << "Gasoline" << endl << setw(20) << "Driven" << " " 
   << setw(16) << "Used" << " " <<  setw(16) << "Cost" << endl << endl;

   while(!inputFile.eof()){
      inputFile >> milesDriven >> gallonsUsed >> gasolineCost;

      cout << x << " " << setw(17) << milesDriven << " " << setw(17) 
      << fixed << setprecision(2) << gallonsUsed << " " << setw(12) << fixed 
      << setprecision << gasolineCost << endl ;
      x++;
   }

   //Process Each Trip

   /*while(inputFile)

      { sumMilesDriven = sumMilesDriven + milesDriven;

      inputFile >> milesDriven;    

      }*/

   for (; milesDriven--;) 
      sumMilesDriven += milesDriven;

   cout << endl << "Sum" << " " << setw(15) << sumMilesDriven ;

   for (;gallonsUsed;)
      sumGallonsUsed += gallonsUsed;

   cout << " " << setw(17) << sumGallonsUsed;

   for (;gasolineCost--;)
      sumGasolineCost += gasolineCost;

   inputFile.close( );

   return 0;
}
```

I've gotten this far and I can't figure out what's wrong. I've taken out the `milesDriven >=10` from the for loop parenthesis. When the code runs I get an incorrect sum amount. The sum is either too big or too small.

Comment: What language? JS? python? Add a tag.

Comment: Is `sumMilesDriven` declared somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Right now, you are trying to add into `sumMilesDriven` from variable that really doesn't change in a sane manner.  Usually for assignments like this, you either read in from an "array" of data, or you need to cin/input data from soemwhere and then sum that in your loop.  You will then need a way to know when all the data has been entered so that you know when to break out of your loop.

Comment: I'm using c++ and yes sumMilesDriven is declared in  the code.

Comment: Your code is obviously not complete. Please paste in the complete code.

Comment: your code is really a chaos. Please learn how to indent properly

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
for (sumGasolineCost += gasolineCost; gasolineCost >= 1; gasolineCost--);{ 
 cout << " " << setw(17) << sumGasolineCost;
}
```

My first advice is, *do not write confusing code*.  Whenever you're programming, you have better things to do than tie your shoelaces together.  I think you know the above is equivalent to:

```
for (sumGasolineCost += gasolineCost; gasolineCost >= 1; gasolineCost--);

cout << " " << setw(17) << sumGasolineCost;
```

That lets us discuss the loop itself.  Go back and consult your textbook.  The for loop has three components:

```
for( init ; test ; incr )
```

- *init* is executed once, usually to initialize what will be tested
- *test* is executed on each iteration, including the first, to determine if the loop body will be executed
- *incr* is executed after the loop body, usually to update the tested value

In your case, `sumGasolineCost += gasolineCost` is in `init`.  It is executed once.  It should be in the loop body.  There are other errors, too.  I can't be much more specific because you don't indicate where the array or input is that you're looping over.

Once you get your loop doing what it should, you might find the standard std::accumulate function interesting to compare to.

Comment: I'm going through and fixing my errors now my numbers are much closer than they were before but I'm not quite there yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I 've gone through it again and it's not working. I've tried this  
            for (;milesDriven >=1; milesDriven--) 
                
                sumMilesDriven+=  milesDriven;

Comment: The code I see has `milesDriven` initialized to zero. Unless there's something else going on, the test `milesDriven >=1` prevents the loop from executing.

Comment: I removed the milesDriven >=1 and it's still giving me the wrong number.